# Consulta MySQL para visualizar el conteo de un campo (por sus calores) en varias columnas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy utilizando

- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64)

---

La siguiente consulta arroja el lenguaje de los libros por autor (author_id)

```
select author_id, language, count(author_id) as c_languaje_books
from books 
group by author_id, language;
```

Se muestra en el siguiente formato, fila de español y fila de ingles (en este ejemplo solo hay un autor)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi pregunta es:**

- Cómo debería elaborar la consulta (solo con la tabla books) si deseo que me muestre el resultado de la siguiente manera - columna de español y columna de inglés (en este ejemplo hay dos autores)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gracias por la ayuda**

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr lo que te propones debes hacer uso de un condicional para realizar el conteo.

SQL es un lenguaje que permite realizar consultas a una base de datos relacional de manera muy intuitiva. La sintaxis es bastante peculiar, ya que es casi como si diéramos ordenes al equipo en un idioma humano, en este caso el Inglés.

Debemos pensar lo que queremos y luego dar la orden adecuada usando la sintaxis de SQL.

En este caso quieres:

1. Una lista de la tabla `books`.
2. Que contenga el campo `author_id`.
3. Que contenga el número de libros en idioma español (`es`)
4. Que contenga el numero de libros en idioma inglés (`en`)
5. Agrupado por autor.

Con esta información ya podemos construir nuestra consulta.

Vamos por paso:

1. Una lista de la tabla books: `SELECT ... FROM books`
2. Que contenga el campo `author_id`: `SELECT author_id FROM books`
3. Que contenga el número de libros en idioma español: ???? Y como hago eso?

Bueno, yo te enseñaré una forma como lo puedes hacer.

Usaremos la cláusula `COUNT`, que como su nombre sugiere sirve para contar. Pero ¿Cómo le decimos a SQL que cuente solo los libros en español? Bueno, la respuesta no es muy obvia, pero una vez que lo explique será fácil de entender.

Como dije al principio, SQL es muy amigable. Tanto que se parece a como hablamos los humanos. Si un humano hiciese la tarea, haría lo siguiente:

Toma un libro, si es en español lo cuenta, si es en inglés no.

Eso mismo debemos decirle al motor de base de datos que haga. Y para eso podemos usar la cláusula `CASE WHEN`. Puedes consultar [CASE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) de la documentación oficial de MySQL.

No te daré la explicación completa aqui. Para eso tienes el manual. Pero si te diré que con esta cláusula puedes tomar decisiones según sea el **caso**, de allí su nombre.

Le debemos decir qué vamos a analizar, en este ejemplo es el campo `language`: `CASE language`

Luego le diremos qué caso vamos a tomar en cuenta, en este ejemplo, el caso es `language = 'es'`, entonces ponemos lo siguiente: `CASE language WHEN language = 'es' ...`

Ahora debemos decirle qué hacer cuando consigue un libro en español. Nuestra cláusula `CASE` devuelve un resultado o realiza una operación si se lo pedimos. Sin embargo, `CASE` no sabe contar, solo sabe tomar decisiones, quien cuenta es `COUNT`. ¿Cómo sabe `COUNT` que debe contar el libro? Pues hacemos que `CASE` se lo diga.

Vamos a decirle a `CASE` que nos devuelva un valor `TRUE`. De esta manera, cada vez que consigue un libro `es` devuelve `TRUE` y así `COUNT` entiende que debe contarlo. Y para eso usamos `THEN`, de esta forma el código se ve así: `CASE language WHEN language = 'es' THEN TRUE ...`

Ahora falta decirle a `CASE` que ya ha terminado de analizar los casos. Debemos terminar nuestra sentencia `CASE` con la palabra `END`. Entonces nuestro código debe lucir así: `CASE language WHEN language = 'es' THEN TRUE END`

El mismo razonamiento aplica para contar los libros en Inglés.

Ahora si podemos continuar con lo que falta.

3. Que contenga el número de libros en idioma español: `COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'es' THEN TRUE END) AS c_language_books_es`
4. Que contenga el número de libros en idioma inglés: `COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'en' THEN TRUE END) AS c_language_books_en`
5. Agrupado por autor: `GROUP BY author_id`

Con eso ya tenemos la consulta que necesitamos. Quedaría así:

```
SELECT author_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'es' THEN TRUE END) AS c_language_book_es, COUNT(CASE WHEN language = 'en' THEN TRUE END) AS c_language_book_en FROM `books` GROUP BY author_id
```

Espero que esto sea la solución a tu problema.

Saludos